# How to modify the levenshtein edit distance function to be more flexible

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

I am looking to find a version of the levenshtein edit distance function that has 3 main differences.

1. It works with tokenized inputs, so instead of `'hello world'` its `['hello', 'world']`. So each char would instead be treated as a word comparing to the other word as a whole. So distance of `['hello', 'world']` and `['world', 'hello']` is 2 for 2 updates. By default the common implementations already seems to work like this anyways if I pass them as tokenized inputs.
2. I want to define a custom number cost for insert, update and delete. The [npm natural.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural#string-distance) seems to support this.
3. I want to define a custom function to checking equality. All the implementation right now use `===` or don't have a way to change this.

The below is the best I could do so far by slightly modifying the code from the link below. It seems to work with #1 and #3 above, but I don't know how to modify this code below to do #2.

```
// https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
function levenshtein(a, b, customCheck) {
    var t = [], u, i, j, m = a.length, n = b.length;
    if (!m) { return n; }
    if (!n) { return m; }
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) { t[j] = j; }
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (u = [i], j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            u[j] = customCheck(a[i - 1], b[j - 1]) ? t[j - 1] : Math.min(t[j - 1], t[j], u[j - 1]) + 1;
        } t = u;
    } return u[n];
}

function customCheck(a, b) {
    return a === b;
}
```

Does anyone know?

---

EDIT: Tried this but it gave me cost of 1. I made cost of removal 100, cost of update 1 and cost of insert 10. I was expecting cost of 100 for removal of `b`.

```
function levenshtein(a, b, customCheck) {
    var t = [], u, i, j, m = a.length, n = b.length;
    if (!m) { return n; }
    if (!n) { return m; }
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) { t[j] = j; }
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (u = [i], j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            u[j] = customCheck(a[i - 1], b[j - 1]) ? t[j - 1] : Math.min(t[j - 1] + 100, t[j] + 1, u[j - 1] + 10); // removal, update, insert
        } t = u;
    }
}

function customCheck(a, b) {
    return a === b;
}

console.log(levenshtein('ab', 'a', customCheck));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in this part:

```
 Math.min(t[j - 1], t[j], u[j - 1]) + 1
```

`t[j - 1]` is the cost before removal on `a`, `t[j]` is the cost of replacing, and `u[j - 1]` is the cost of removal on `b` (or insertion on `a`). 1 is the cost of the current step, so all operations. We can safely move 1 into the `Math.min`:

```
 Math.min(t[j - 1] + 1, t[j] + 1, u[j - 1] + 1)
```

and then you can change the cost for each type easily.

Comment: Thanks, however I tried this (shown above), but it gave me the wrong cost for my test case. I put the code above.

Comment: Will have a look tomorrow... could it be that I mixed up the order? What does `levenshtein("a", "ab")` return?